# Sending multiple parameter(hash table ie. NSDictionary) to a ruby on rails server

Tags: iphone, json

I have been trying to create an NSDictionary of the parameters in my iPhone application and want to send it across(through a POST HTTP request, there are some other parameters also in the request) to a ruby on rails server to be consumed by a ruby method which takes a hash table as arguments.

1. Do I need to serialize the NSDictionary in my iPhone client? How do I do that.
2. I am using JSON but dont see any such JSON feature which can be used.

Comment: [How to use JSON in Cocoa/Objective-C](http://zachwaugh.com/2009/01/how-to-use-json-in-cocoaobjective-c/)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you need to encode parameters explicitly.

It's relatively straightforward.  Here's a extension to NSMutableURLRequest that I use which encodes a dictionary of strings as POST parameters.

```
@interface NSMutableURLRequest (WebServiceClient) 

+ (NSString *) encodeFormPostParameters: (NSDictionary *) parameters;
- (void) setFormPostParameters: (NSDictionary *) parameters;

@end

@implementation NSMutableURLRequest (WebServiceClient)

+ (NSString *) encodeFormPostParameters: (NSDictionary *) parameters {
  NSMutableString *formPostParams = [[[NSMutableString alloc] init] autorelease];

  NSEnumerator *keys = [parameters keyEnumerator];

  NSString *name = [keys nextObject];
  while (nil != name) {
    NSString *encodedValue = [((NSString *) CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (CFStringRef) [parameters objectForKey: name], NULL, CFSTR("=/:"), kCFStringEncodingUTF8)) autorelease];

    [formPostParams appendString: name];
    [formPostParams appendString: @"="];
    [formPostParams appendString: encodedValue];

    name = [keys nextObject];

    if (nil != name) {
      [formPostParams appendString: @"&"];
    }
  }

  return formPostParams;
}

- (void) setFormPostParameters: (NSDictionary *) parameters {
  NSString *formPostParams = [NSMutableURLRequest encodeFormPostParameters: parameters];

  [self setHTTPBody: [formPostParams dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [self setValue: @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
}

@end
```

Comment: Hi dmercredi,
Thanks for the details, but I want to send the NSDictionary so that my method in ruby(which takes a hash table) can still refer the complete set of parameters by the dictionary name.
Use case:
1) Create a NSDictionary(with name "myAttributes") with attributes and values, for a set of attributes to be used in ruby on the server side.
2) Send the NSDictionary as a HTTP POST request body, the method in ruby should be able to refer the received dictionary as "params[:myAttributes]" which gets me all the attributes on the server side, which can be interpreted their after.

TIA.

Comment: OK, I understand. You'll need to use a third party JSON library, there isn't one in the iPhone API. I use TouchJSON in my app because it parses very quickly directly from NSData. 

See http://code.google.com/p/touchcode/wiki/TouchJSON 

As long as the dictionary contains only NSString, NSNull, or NSNumber, NSDictionary, or NSArray you can use CJSONSerialer in TouchJSON to create a JSON string, and then set the HTTP body (using UTF8 encoding) and the content-type appropriately similarly to setFormPostParameters in the code.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, tried using TouchJSON but after serializing the NSDictionary and setting it in the HTTP body for my POST request the attribute values I see in ruby are little different.
Ruby expects something like: events=>{"name"=>"ABC", "budget"=>"123"}
but I see: events=>{\"name\"=\"ABC\", \"budget\" = \"123\"}

Is there a similar iPhone/Ruby on rails, example to send hash table parameters to ruby from Cocoa using NSDictionary which can be referred here? Thanks.

Comment: you need to use JSON.parse(request)